Keycloak - reorder first-time login steps
In our app we register users in a way that we create a new user in Keycloak and send them an invitation email.
When the user clicks the link they are asked to setup their password. This is great.
For some users though we enable Required action "Configure OTP" as we want them to setup 2FA from the get-go.
The flow is then:

Configure OTP (scan QR code etc.)
Set password

We would like to flip these steps like so:

Set password
Configure OTP

We use the Built-in Browser authentication flow. Keycloak version 25.0.6.
I tried to copy the flow and move steps around but so far I only managed to break the whole process.

Go to Keycloak admin console, under your realm > Authentication > Required actions, drag "Configure OTP" to below "Update Password".
